# SQLite: Inserting values from table in database1 to table in database2 without overwriting

Tags: sql, sqlite, merge, inner-join

I really can't wrap my head around this. We're two dudes manually writing textbits in conflicting databases (I know, it's not cool), and now we need to integrate our work. Sorry if it's a duplicate, but I don't get it from the other answers. Please be patient, I need help here.

Two different databases needs to merge one column, and if possible, avoid overwriting.

```
His database:         My database:     RESULT:

Database 1            Database 2        Database 2
Table1                Table1            Table1
A Column              A Column          A Column

Blah                  NULL              Blah
NULL                  Bla               Bla
Bla                   Bla               Bla Bla
```

I'm guessing INNER JOIN mixed with a INSERT INTO?

We're working in a GUI named Valentina Studio with an SQL editor.

Comment: Is there some ID column?

Comment: Yes! They have the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
Insert into tab3 (col1) 
Select col1 from tab1 where col1 is not null
Union 
select col1 from tab2 where col1 is not null
```

Comment: Hm, but that doesn't include the 'cross-database' element, does it?

Comment: Union will remove duplicates. If not, do a outside query like : select distinct col1 from (the query...) a

Answer (score 0):

When your own value is NULL, you want to copy the other value:

```
UPDATE db2.Table1
SET AColumn = (SELECT AColumn
               FROM db1.Table1
               WHERE db1.Table1.ID = db2.Table1.ID)
WHERE AColumn IS NULL;
```

When your own column has a value, you want to append the other value, if it is not NULL:

```
UPDATE db2.Table1
SET AColumn = AColumn || IFNULL((SELECT ' ' || AColumn
                                 FROM db1.Table1
                                 WHERE db1.Table1.ID = db2.Table1.ID),
                                '')
WHERE AColumn IS NOT NULL;
```